# Button must be clicked twice in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple window with a TextBox and a Button which closes the window. But I must click it twice! First time I click it, the IPv4 setter is called. The second time the SubmitCommand's ExecuteSubmit() function gets called. Why?!
I am learning wpf, so all this is pretty new for me.

(The AcceptsReturn is just a test, it makes no difference)

```
<Window x:Class="MiniServer.WindowEnterIPAddress"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiniServer" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModelMiniServerSettings}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Enter IP" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding IPv4}" AcceptsReturn="False" />
        <Label Content="{Binding ErrorMessage}"/>
        <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The SubmitCommand uses the simple RelayCommand class, my version is almost identical to the one here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/

`SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(o => ExecuteSubmit(), o => true);`

Thank's for any help!

---

I found a workaround with the help of Arkane's idea in the comments, basically this:

Move the validation of the IPv4 from the IPv4 setter to the button SubmitCommand. If validation fails, an error message is shown and button does nothing more.

Secondly, since I wanted enter to 'click the button' I wanted to set IsDefault on the button. However, that forced me to set the textbox UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <!-- Note: TextBox must have PropertyChanged in combination with IsDefault set to true, otherwise changes is not propagated to the ViewModel when hitting enter. -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding IPv4, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding ErrorMessage}"/>
    <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you have debugging breakpoints set in the setter and the submit command?

Comment: I believe it is because when you first click on the button, the textbox loses focus and calls the setter (That's because the default trigger is `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"`, if I'm not mistaken), but it suprises me that the click event is not triggered on the button. Do you have a breakpoint in the 'IPv4' property setter? What happens if you change the TextBox binding to `{Binding IPv4, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}`?

Comment: thatguy, Arkane, no breakpoints at all. I have tested with breakpoints to see code is working of course, but normally no breakpoints. Changing to PropertyChanged works! Although I don't want it to validate user input on every keystroke..

Comment: Arkane, since your proposal works, it must mean (without your fix) the mouse click event gets swallowed by the textbox validation code which run when it looses focus. That kind of makes it impossible.. Any workaround on this?